# How to query SQLite table based on 2 arguments?

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to query my SQLite table based on 2 columns which equal the values of a jList and jtextfield. I have set a ListSelectionListener to wait for which "date" is selected from the list. I know my code is wrong for the select statement, but I am unable to find any other online assistance which has an example I can relate to. Any help would be great!
Thank you

A basic example here:

```
listJobCostDates = new JList();
        listJobCostDates.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                String jobNumber = txtJobNumber.getText().toString();
                Object dateNumber = listJobCostDates.getSelectedValue();

                String sql = "SELECT * FROM JOBCOSTS where Job_Number,Date='" +jobNumber+"'" AND Date =+dateNumber+"'"  ;

                try {

                    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    while(rs.next()) {
                    tblDayJobCosts.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

                    }

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: https://bobby-tables.com/java

Comment: `where Job_Number = '" +jobNumber+ "' and Date ='"+dateNumber+"'`

Answer (score 0):

Your where condition is not correct

```
 String sql = "SELECT * FROM JOBCOSTS where Job_Number = '" +jobNumber+ "' and Date ='"+dateNumber+"'"
```

But above is prone to sql injection, use `Prepared Statements` instead.

```
 pst=conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM JOBCOSTS where Job_Number = ? and Date = ?);
 pst.setString(1, jobNumber);
 pst.setString(2, dateNumber);
```

Comment: @JillJohn, see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp